# Issues with popup timer resetting

Tags: javascript

This is my first time working with JavaScript, so I'm sure this is a simple question, but I can't figure it out. Basically, I am creating a game and I need to add a function so that if the player hasn't moved for 20 seconds, they receive a reminder.

I have it working to the point that the reminder will pop-up 20 seconds after the player has last clicked, but it seems to keep popping up, regardless of whether they have moved within the 20 seconds or not.

Here is my code:

```
function UpdateMoveCount() {
  var timer = setInterval(setReminderTimer, 1000);
  var moveReminder = 0;

  function setReminderTimer() {
    if(moveReminder == 20) {
      document.getElementById("move").style.visibility = "visible";  
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      moveReminder++;
    }
  }
}
```

`UpdateMoveCount()` is called each time the player clicks.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In your code there is nothing to reset/clear the timer after they have moved.

Comment: How would I do that though? I assumed `clearInterval()` would do the job?

Comment: Also, why don't you just set a single setTimeout lasting 20 seconds when the user moves? You can clear it as soon as a new move is performed.

Comment: your `clearInterval()` clears the interval only when it has run for 20 times, independently from the fact that anything (a move) has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var timer = null;
function UpdateMoveCount() {
  if(timer) clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(setReminderTimer, 1000);
  var moveReminder = 0;

  function setReminderTimer() {
    if(moveReminder == 20) {
      document.getElementById("move").style.visibility = "visible";  
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      moveReminder++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because when user clicks,you use setInterval but you dont check whether user moves after clicking the button.Hence,user will get pop-up after 20 seconds of clicking button
Make a function to check whether user has moved and use clearInterval inside it too

```
function UpdateMoveCount() {
var timer = setInterval(setReminderTimer, 1000);
var moveReminder = 0;

function setReminderTimer() {

  if(UserMoved) clearInterval(timer);

  else if(moveReminder == 20) {
     document.getElementById("move").style.visibility = "visible";  
    clearInterval(timer);
    }
   else {
    moveReminder++;
    }
 }
}
```